# Auto update feature in passbook ios 7

Tags: ios6, passbook, passkit

How does automatic updates work in passbook available in backfield of the pass, how to use webserviceURL key to get update from the server.

in webserviceURL key i have provided remote path from where updated pass can be  downloaded, but even after content changed in server, it does not reflects in pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been asked so many times, in so many ways, in so many forums; mostly by people that are too lazy to [read the manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988), or are too inexperienced / incompetent to understand it.

The first paragraph of the [Passbook Web Service Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988) explains why simply adding a link to an updated pass will not work.

> *A REST-style web service protocol is used to communicate with your server about changes to passes, and to fetch the latest version of a pass when it has changed. The endpoints always begin with the web service URL, as specified in the pass, followed by the protocol version number. For example, a request for the latest version of the pass of type com.apple.pass.example and serial number ABC123 might look like the following:*

[image]

The Passbook web service is an integral part of the Passbook eco system.  Anyone wishing to issue passes that change their content (either in response to a push message or in response to a user requesting fresh content by pulling down on the back of the pass), needs to implement their own Passbook web service.

This entails building a server capable of responding to the following to authenticated requests from each device that has installed your pass.

There are 5 methods that your web service should respond to:

---

**1. Registering a Device to Receive Push Notifications for a Pass**

`POST` request to https://***webServiceURL***/v1/devices/***deviceLibraryIdentifier***/registrations/***passTypeIdentifier***/***serialNumber***

---

**2. Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device**

`GET` request to https://***webServiceURL***/v1/devices/***deviceLibraryIdentifier***/registrations/***passTypeIdentifier***?passesUpdatedSince=***tag***

---

**3. Getting the Latest Version of a Pass**

`GET` request to https://***webServiceURL***/v1/passes/***passTypeIdentifier***/***serialNumber***

---

**4. Unregistering a Device**

`DELETE` request to https://***webServiceURL***/v1/devices/***deviceLibraryIdentifier***/registrations/***passTypeIdentifier***/***serialNumber***

---

**5. Logging Errors**

`POST` request to https://***webServiceURL***/v1/log

---

In order to have a pass respond to a manual refresh or push request you need to implement at least the first 3 methods.  This is because the device will not issue any further requests until it has received a valid response to the registration request.

Furthermore, the web service must be available over `https`.  An unsecured `http` service can be used for development, but production devices will only recognise a webServiceURL key that begins with `https`.